# Conditionally disable scroll to top on dom change react router

Tags: reactjs, scroll, react-router

I've implemented a ScrollToTop component inside my Browser Router so the scroll position is (0,0) on every new dom change.

i.e.) /explore > /about will scroll to top.

However, within the explore page I have a tab-like submenu(Home, Items, Budget) which manipulates the router to scroll to top when it shouldn't. The Home tab takes default path of Explore while Items and Budget are a nested routes inside the Explore.

i.e.) /explore > /explore/items or /explore > /explore/budget

I've tried to use conditions in my ScrollToTop component but failed. I've looked at React router training restoration scroll guide but wasn't successful. Would anyone know how to conditionally disable scroll to top on certain pathnames or locations?

Here is my ScrollToTop:

```
const ScrollToTop = (props) => {

  useEffect(() => {
    if (props.history.action === 'POP') {
        return;
    }

    let hash = props.location.hash;
    if (hash) {
      let element = document.querySelector(hash);
      if (element) {
        element.scrollIntoView({block: 'start', behavior: 'smooth'});
      }
    } else {
      window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    }    
  });
};
```

Comment: You will have to share you implementation of ScrollToTop

Comment: @TomFinney I just updated my post :)

Comment: @episodewon You could write your approach as an answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite know what you've already tried but based on your code snippet, I threw together this quick sandbox showing how to block that: https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-river-3bjf5

You can see that if you scroll the page and click the `thisthat` link it doesn't scroll to the top but does for the other links.

I guess the key things are that we render the component by passing it to a `Route` so it directly receives all the router props `<Route component={ScrollToTop} />` (you could use the withRouter decorator or something but they all achieve the same goal)

Then, it just has a list of pathnames like `const dontScrollIntoViewOnPaths = ["/this/that"];`

We pluck out the most recent pathname from the location `let { hash, pathname } = location;`

And then we just don't execute the code unless the pathname is NOT in the that list

```
 else if (!dontScrollIntoViewOnPaths.includes(pathname)) {
      window.scrollTo(0, 0);
 }
```

Is that helpful?

Comment: Great, thanks for your feedback! I thought I had tried something like that..

I ended up implementing previous location so it only blocks scrollToTop only within the nested routes :)

Answer (score -1):

There's a prop in the react-router-dom `<Router />` component that can be set to `true` to turn it off:

`disableScrollToTop={true}`